# Can MAE be reported in percentage?

Tags: machine-learning, error, standardization, mae

In Wang et al. ["Predicting New Workload or CPU Performance by Analyzing Public Datasets"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3284127) (2019), the MAE is measured in a standardized space (Mean=0, SD=1). This is discussed in **3.4 Metrics**, page 9.

Then right after Figure 6 on page 12, all the MAE references in the paper are presented in percentage, e.g. the average MAE is 5.5.%.

Why is MAE reported in percentage? Does it have anything to do with standardization?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't read the paper in detail (though their equation (2), where they claim that the MAE against the mean is the standard deviation, casts some doubt on the statistical expertise involved). If you divide the MAE by the mean of the time series, you can interpret the result as a weighted Mean Absolute Percentage Error (wMAPE; see [Kolassa & Schütz, 2007](https://ideas.repec.org/a/for/ijafaa/y2007i6p40-43.html)). This may be what the authors calculated.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan. I guess in that equation, they are just saying that with a naive predictor (that always predicts the mean), then our MAE will be the same as SD. But in any case, the mean is 0, right? so how can we divide the MAE by the mean? (btw, I couldn't access your paper, was only able to read the abstract) I am using simple MAPE to reproduce their results. What do you think?

Comment: "with a naive predictor (that always predicts the mean), then our MAE will be the same as SD" - if they are saying that, they are wrong, because the SD is defined differently from what they seem to be thinking. And no, if the mean is 0 (are you referring to the normalization?), then of course we can't divide by it. I don't have the time to dig deeply into that paper, sorry. Feel free to request my paper on ResearchGate. You may be interested in [What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352)

Comment: @thanks Stephan. Yes, you are right, SD is calculated differently. Yes, the mean is 0, they have used standardization (Mean=0, SD=1). Although, I had read your post about the shortcomings of MAPE, I'd be interested to read more, so I'll send a request. However, I don'tthink wMAPE is gonna work here then. So, I guess I have to stick with MAPE, if I'm looking for a percentage calculation?

Comment: If you want a percentage error with respect to the underlying series, then you will likely need to do something like MAPE, or MPE.

Answer (score 3):

Mean absolute error is defined as an average of the absolute differences between observed values $y_i$ and the predictions for them $\hat y_i$

$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n |y_i - \hat y_i|}{n}
$$

So it is *not* a percentage of anything.

My *guess* is that they mean that the error is measured in [percentage point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point) units, because their target is the relative runtime (p. 3), i.e. by how many percentage points does the runtime differ from the reference runtime. In such case, you can say that the machine learning model makes predictions that are off by some amount of relative runtime units, hence the percentage points.

But I must say, that I agree with Stephan Kolassa, that it is rather strange that they discuss things like standard deviations or normal distributions while discussing MAE, so I'd take the discussion with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. I'm also not sure if they really mean the percentage point, because they also present an example in 3.4 item 2 on why they have used MAE:  _If a prediction is x and the MAE of the model is 0.01, the real value of x is very likely to be x ± 0.01_ which is the common definition of MAE

Comment: @towi_parallelism as said, it is a guess, they don't say it explicitly. The quote you provide however makes it more likely, since if they meant % of something, than the "likely" value would be x ± MAE \* *something*.

Comment: Thanks Tim. That makes sense, but I still wonder why it has not been explained clearly. I am trying to contact the authors directly. If I get any further information, I'll post an update here